# SUDS Custom Header

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, soap-client, suds

I'm new to Python and I use *suds* for *wsdl* client. How can I create custom request header for this.

XML get from SOAP UI :

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <sbus:SBusContext message-tracking-id="?" correlation-id="?" entry-dtime="?" timestamp="?" entry-system="?" entry-system-principal="?" entry-url="?" priority="?">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <sbus:Keys>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <sbus:Key keyType="?" keyValDataType="string">
               <sbus:KeyValue>?</sbus:KeyValue>
            </sbus:Key>
         </sbus:Keys>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <sbus:ExtContext>?</sbus:ExtContext>
      </sbus:SBusContext>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT -

I realized you're probably asking about a SOAP header, not an http header.  If so, ignore my answer.  My bad.

---

Take a look here: [How to add http headers in suds 0.3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804062/how-to-add-http-headers-in-suds-0-3-6)

You can add the header when creating the client like this:

```
client = suds.client.Client(url, headers={'key': 'value'})
```

Or after the client is created, by using set_options like this:

```
client.set_options(headers={'key2': 'value'})
```

Worth noting that the original suds package is no longer maintained (last release Sept 2010). It lacks various features you might want, like gzip compression (so don't bother adding an 'accept-encoding:gzip' header if you're using the old suds package).  Various forks have sprung up.  I believe the most active of them is suds-jurko.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet from official SUDS [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/wiki/Original%20Documentation):

```
from suds.sax.element import Element
client = client(url)
ssnns = ('ssn', 'http://namespaces/sessionid')
ssn = Element('SessionID', ns=ssnns).setText('123')
client.set_options(soapheaders=ssn) 
result = client.service.addPerson(person)
```

Comment: hello piotr, seeking for the same answer, i find your answer the only one working of the many showed in the documentation. as my solution required 2 headers, i will also post an answer. all my best.

Answer (score 0):

i needed to add 2 soap headers with xmlns.
i found the solution following the [answer of @piotr sz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45009052/4444742).
here is the solution as i needed it:

```
userName = Element('UserName').setText(fco.user)
password = Element('Password').setText(fco.pwd)
fdxns = Attribute('xmlns', "http://fdx.co.il/Authentication")
for field in userName, password:
    field.append(fdxns)
client.set_options(soapheaders=(userName, password))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin security feature in suds to set the securityheader

```
from suds.wsse import Security, UsernameToken
url = 'http://something.some/service.svc?wsdl'
client= Client(url, faults=False)
security = Security()
token = UsernameToken('username', 'password')
token.setcreated()
security.tokens.append(token)
client.set_options(wsse=security)
```