# suds (SOAP) - server raised fault - not specified parameter 'username'

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I'm trying to use method from soap defined webservice. I was able to connect and get information about method, but when I try to use that method, then I get error saying

`Server raised fault: 'Unspecified parameter 'username''`

So I gues when I want to send data to server, for some reason it tries to send without username?
I tried to connect (authenticate) to webservice various ways described in suds documentation: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation

Either approach gives above error.

For example I've written like this:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
from suds.client import Client
from suds import WebFault
#from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

url = 'some_url?wsdl'
t = HttpAuthenticated()
client = Client(url, transport=t, username='username', password='password')
#print client
card = client.factory.create('Type1')
cs = card.subtype
cs.param1 = 25
cs.param2 = 26
cs.param3 = '1234567891'



try:
    card_created = client.service.method1(card)
except WebFault, e:
    print e
```

Whole error with Envelope looks like this:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope
xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><S:Fault     
xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>  
<faultstring>Unspecified parameter 'username'</faultstring><detail><ns2:Exception  
xmlns:ns2="http://some_other_url/"><message>Unspecified parameter
```

'username'
    Server raised fault: 'Unspecified parameter 'username''

I also tried solution from similar problem in here:
http://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/inapickle/2011/05/14/exchange-web-services-suds-and-python/
But it didn't help. **Update** - I also tried some suds forks, but still the same problem (to be specific - `suds-jurko` and `suds-ews`).

How could I force suds to use method by specifying authentication (and other details if it might be missing afterwards)?

**Update2**
When I changed authentication implementation like this (Actually very similar to approach I posted above):

```
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
t = HttpAuthenticated(username='username', password='password')
client = Client(url, transport=t)
```

And then when I try to use method (the same I written above), I get this error:

```
    <i>Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1</i>:</H3>
    </FONT><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H4>10.4.2 401 Unauthorized</H4>
    </FONT><P><FONT FACE="Courier New">The request requires user authentication. The
 response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.46) containing a 
challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a
 suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included 
Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been 
refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the 
prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once,
 then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that
 entity MAY include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is 
explained in section 11.</FONT></P>
```

So I think with previous methods server was not seeing username, but now for some reason it just rejects authorization? Could it be something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I could only authenticate when I specified username/password headers "manually" like this:

```
client = Client(url, headers = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'})
```

Idea came from JK1 answer in [How to add http headers in suds 0.3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804062/how-to-add-http-headers-in-suds-0-3-6)